# ntheorem: extra space between a proof and a theorem

Tags: ntheorem

In `ntheorem`, when I have a proof that ends with a displayed equation that is immediately followed by a theorem, I seem to get too much space between the equation and the theorem.

In my example, I assume the space around the first displayed equation should match the space around the second, but there is excessive space under the first displayed equation. Can anything be done other than adding a negative `\vspace` command after the first displayed equation?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage[standard,amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Text.
\begin{gather}
1+1=2.
\end{gather}
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
Text (automatic theorem).
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Text.
\begin{gather}
1+1=2.
\end{gather}
\end{proof}

\noindent
\textbf{Theorem 1}
\emph{Text (manual theorem).}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the extra space, you may try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage[standard,amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\theorempreskip{0pt}
\renewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

    \begin{proof}
        Text.
        \begin{gather}
        1+1=2.
        \end{gather}
    \end{proof}

    \begin{theorem}
        Text (automatic theorem).
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{proof}
        Text.
        \begin{gather}
        1+1=2.
        \end{gather}
    \end{proof}

    \noindent
    \textbf{Theorem 1}
    \emph{Text (manual theorem).}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was actually wondering if this is an `ntheorem` bug and if there was a known way to fix it.

Comment: But it does seem that under the first displayed equation, I'm getting one below-displayed-math space plus one above/below-theorem space. In other words, it seems that `ntheorem` is removing the space after the proof but leaving the space before the theorem, when it should also be removing the space before the theorem.

Comment: In ntheorem, isn't the theorem skips shared, that is one cannot make individual skips for the various theorem constructions